# handling rails controller exceptions/errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, nomethoderror

I have a controller action that approves a `blob`, and which throws a `NoMethodError` on `do_this()`:

```
def approve
 if amount >= 0
  @blob.accept
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to blobs_path, notice: "accepted #{do_this(@blob)}" }
   format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @blob }
  end
 else
  @blob.reject
  redirect_to blobs_path, notice: "deleted."
 end
end
```

My solution is to change the `#{do_this(@blob)}` to `#{helpers.do_this(@blob)}`. But there's one problem: `@blob` was already approved, and the error was outside of the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` I have inside the `accept` method. Changing the code and refreshing the page pushes that transaction through twice. :/

I know that it's not good to put transactions inside controllers, but what if I anticipate something similar in the future? How would I avoid this?

Comment: what's `do_this` doing and where's defined? what's `accept` doing?

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference what `do_this` and `accept` do because my question is about what happens outside of those functions? Reread the Q - the record is created, but a NoMethodError is caused by the fact that I did not preface the helper in my controller with `helpers.`. Refreshing the page pushes that record through a second time, and I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding an `unapproved` scope to `@blob`. If `@blob.accept` marks something as approved, then it should only act on records that have not been accepted. Wow, big duh.